# Getting date and time using HTML input type 'date' and 'time' but will not get inserted into mysql using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, time

First time on here so sorry if I get the formatting wrong!

I have a createperform.php file which has a form that links back to itself. The performancedate and performancetime is posted along with the prod for productionID. I have a database Table called Performance, which has 4 columns (PerformanceID(Auto Inc, int), ProductionID(int), performancedate(date) & performancetime(time))

```
<form action="createperform.php" method="POST" role="form">
        <input type="date" required="required" name="performancedate" id="performancedate" />   
        <input type="time" required="required" name="performancetime" id="performancetime" />       
        <select name="prod">
            <?php
                while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['productionID'] . '">' . $row['productionname'] . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>               
        <br><br> 
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitPerform" class="btn btn-default">Create Performance</button>
    </form>
```

Here is my PHP at the top of the createperform.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("includes/adminheader.php");
include("db.php");

$results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Production");

if (isset($_POST["submitPerform"]))
{
    $performancedate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["performancedate"]);
    $performancetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["performancetime"]).":00";
    $prodID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["prod"]);

    $aresult = $conn->query("INSERT INTO Performance (productionID, performancedate, performancetime,)
    VALUES('{$prodID}','2015-06-23','02:34:24')");

    if ($aresult)
    {
        $message = "Performance successfully added to Production ID: ".$prodID;
    }   
    else
    {
        $message = "Performance failed to get added to Production ID: ".$prodID;
    }
}
?>
```

The db connection is in db.php, I keep getting the else part of the if($aresult) state that executes. I have checked my table names, check my variable names, I am getting no errors at all. I made sure that the format of the date is: YYYY-MM-DD and made sure that the format or the time is HH:MM:SS.

I printed out the values stored in the date and time variables and this is what I got:

```
<br><h3><?php echo $message; echo $performancedate; echo $performancetime;?></h3><br>
Performance failed to get added to Production ID: 52015-03-2923:54:00
```

I have ran out of things that I can try now. If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: I forgot to add that in the example above I even hardcoded the date and time into the mysql query and I still get the else part of the statement executing.

Comment: In your query statement there is one extra ,(comma). Please remove it and try  :  $aresult = $conn->query("INSERT INTO Performance (productionID, performancedate, performancetime)
    VALUES('{$prodID}','2015-06-23','02:34:24')");

Comment: Thank you Azeez, well spotted! I did not notice that at all!

Comment: Yes it was working perfectly after changing that, thank you. How do I make your answer the best answer?

Comment: This is comments section so you cannot make the answer as best answer, but You can up vote that comment. :)

Comment: Ahh I see, I don't believe that is possible for me as my reputation is low. But again, thank you for the help!